# Solving a maze using stacks

Tags: java, stack, maze

I created two stacks. One for the path the other for spots I already searched. Ideally I would check to see if the searched path contains the next spot in a direction. If it does it checks another direction.

Sample maze

0 1 0 1 0

0 0 0 1 0

0 1 0 0 0

0 1 0 1 1

0 1 0 0 0

My algorithm seems to get stuck between 2,3 and 2,4. Never explores 1,4 or 0,4. I see it keep bouncing between 2,3 and 2,4 in an infinite loop. So it seems my searched.contains() is not functioning properly. Any suggestion to fix my searched stack? Ideally, when I run my code. I want it to check East, South, west then North has already been searched or not. If all points have been checked it will pop the last position from my path stack using current= path.pop inside the while loop and repeat.

Position is a custom class. I have considered adding a previous position variable to the constructor in the position class but seems to not to be needed if I can get my path stack to work. If I am wrong on this please let me know.

```
class Position{


public int i;     //row
public int j;     //column
public char val;  //1, 0, or 'X'


// reference to the previous position (parent) that leads to this position on a path
Position parent;

Position(int x, int y, char v){
    i=x; j = y; val=v;
}

Position(int x, int y, char v, Position p){
    i=x; j = y; val=v;
    parent=p;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + i;
    result = prime * result + j;
    result = prime * result + ((parent == null) ? 0 : parent.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + val;
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Position other = (Position) obj;
    if (i != other.i)
        return false;
    if (j != other.j)
        return false;
    if (parent == null) {
        if (other.parent != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!parent.equals(other.parent))
        return false;
    if (val != other.val)
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

}

```
public static Position [] stackSearch(char [] [] maze){
//todo: your path finding algorithm here using the stack to manage search list
//your algorithm should modify maze to mark positions on the path, and also
//return array of Position objects coressponding to path, or null if no path found
 ArrayDeque <Position> path = new ArrayDeque<Position>();
 ArrayDeque <Position> searched = new ArrayDeque<Position>();


    //creates position object
    Position start = new Position(0,0,'0');
    Position current;
    Position north,south, east, west;

    int i = 0; int j = 0;
    //push (0,0) onto stack
    path.push(start);
    searched.push(start);
    while(!path.isEmpty()){
        current=path.pop();
        i=current.i;
        j=current.j;
        if(i==maze.length-1 && j==maze.length-1 &&  maze[i][j]=='0'){
             Position[] trail= new Position [path.size()];
            while(!path.isEmpty()){
                for(int k=0; k<path.size();k++){
                trail[k]=path.pop();
            }
                return trail;
        }
    }
        System.out.println(i +"," +j);

        //check east.
        east= new Position(i,j+1,'0');
        south= new Position(i+1,j,'0');
        west= new Position(i,j-1,'0');
        north= new Position(i-1,j,'0');
        if (j+1 >= 0 && j+1 < maze.length  && maze[i][j+1] == '0' && searched.contains(east)==false)
        {


                searched.push(east);
                path.push(current);
                path.push(east);




        }
        //check south, add its position to the list.

        else if (i+1 >= 0 && i+1 < maze.length &&  maze[i+1][j] == '0' && searched.contains(south)==false)
        {


                searched.push(south);
                path.push(current);
                path.push(south);


        }
      //check west.

         else if (j-1 >= 0 && j-1 < maze.length  && maze[i][j-1] == '0' && searched.contains(west)==false)
        {


                searched.push(west);


                path.push(current);
                path.push(west);

        }              
        //check north

         else if (i-1 >= 0 && i-1 < maze.length &&  maze[i-1][j] == '0' && searched.contains(north)==false)
        {


                searched.push(north);
                path.push(current);
                path.push(north);


        }

   }
return null;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe you are using the stacks correctly. For example, you seem to be using your path stack both to store the final solution to the maze as well as to store parts of paths you have not fully checked (and may not be the correct solution). Your are pushing north, south, east, west onto your path stack, and you are converting the path stack to return as a solution. This won't work. How do you know the north Position leads to a dead end or not? You cannot start adding things to your path stack until you have already determined the final path through the maze.

You can use something called a depth first search to determine a path through the maze:

First, you should use your stack to "manage [your] search list." In other words, you should store all locations to be checked in the stack.

Then, you use the stack to perform a depth first search on the maze. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search

Once you have reached your destination, you should backtrack. Thus, you will probably need to have a previous position variable in your Position class.

Something like this should work...

```
let toSearch be a Stack of positions to search
let visited be a 2D array indicating all locations of the maze we've visited (or a stack, or whatever you prefer)
let start be the starting Position
let end be the ending Position

toSearch.push( start );

while( toSearch is not empty ) {
    posToSearch = toSearch.pop();

    if ( posToSearch is the end ) {
        let s be a stack
        let temp = end

        //backtracking with a stack
        while( temp is not start ) {
            s.push( temp );
            //also modify the maze to indicate the path
            maze[ temp.i ][ temp.j ] = '*';
            temp = temp.previous;
        }
        s.push( start );

        //turn the information in the stack into an array
        let rtn be an array of size s.size()
        for i=0 ... s.size();
            rtn[ i ] = s.pop();

        return rtn;
    }

    if ( posToSearch is not already visited ) {

        if ( you can go north ) {
            start.push( position north of posToSearch );
        }
        if ( you can go south ) {
            start.push( position south of posToSearch ); 
        }
        if (... east ... )
        if (... west ... )

        label posToSearch as visited
    }

}

//if the end was never reached, then there cannot be a solution to the maze
return null;
```